# Two different formatting for different numbers

Tags: sql, formatting

is there any easy and clean solution to have two different formatting for different numbers.
E.g. 0.00 should be 0 and all other numbers should be x.xxx.

My solution so far:

```
select decode(to_char(0.000, '90D999'),'0.000', 0, (to_char (0.000, '99990D99999'))) from dual
```

I am not happy, because I think there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CASE-WHEN...

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN MY_VALUE=0 THEN '0' ELSE to_char(MY_VALUE, '90D999') END) 
FROM DUAL
```

This is a bit more readable I think - but that is subjective...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple-case-expression to make it slightly cleaner:

```
select case my_value when 0 then '0' else to_char(my_value, '90D999') end
from dual;
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Comment: Didn't I post this exact solution 10 minutes ago? (Ok, with a bit different syntax)